# Alternative way to get user Lat and Lng without didUpdateLocations?

Tags: ios, swift, userlocation

Is there an alternative way to get the user's latitude and longitude without using the function `didUpdateLocations`. I only want to do this once and set the initial region when the view is loaded, not every time the user's location is updated.

I know I could get the user's Lat and Lng with the code below but is there an alternative?

```
func locationManager(manager:CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations:[AnyObject]) {

    var userLocation:CLLocation = locations[0] as CLLocation

    var latitude:CLLocationDegrees = userLocation.coordinate.latitude

    var longitude:CLLocationDegrees = userLocation.coordinate.longitude

    var latDelta:CLLocationDegrees = 0.01

    var lonDelta:CLLocationDegrees = 0.01

    var span:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(latDelta, lonDelta)

    var location:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude)

    var region:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(location, span)

    myMap.setRegion(region, animated: true)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is for iOS 9: `CLLocationManager.requestLocation()`. This API is provided just for your purpose - a way to grab a location at a discreet time without turning on continuous tracking.

See [this page](http://nshipster.com/ios9/) for a preview on how it works.

In iOS 8 and lower, I am not aware of an API.